# Setting resultData to null causes duplicate entries to appear in recent apps

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

If I were to say `super.setResultData(null)` in the `onReceive(...)` method of the `BroadcastReceiver`, what appears to be the `Intent` that fired the `BroadcastReceiver` starts to appear in the recent applications view (the one that pops up on long-pressing the home button).

To be more specific, when I make a call from the device's dialer, and my `BroadcastReceiver` captures the `Intent`, I start up an activity and then set the `resultData` to `null`. This for some reasons adds another instance of the dialer to my recent apps. And on clicking this instance, the `BroadcastReceiver.onReceiver(...)` is again fired.

The problem is however resolved if I were to not set the `resultData` to `null`.

What could be the issue here?

*Similar Question : [Native phone dialer ghost appears in recent apps after calling setResultData(null);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862457/native-phone-dialer-ghost-appears-in-recent-apps-after-calling-setresultdatanul?rq=1)*